# How to find a function that is locally Lipschitz, but not Lipschitz overall?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, lipschitz-functions

How to find a function that is locally Lipschitz, but not Lipschitz overall?

This is question for my homework, but I don't understand how that function can exist.

Comment: Every continuously differentiable function is locally Lipschitz.

Comment: *Second Hint.* Every differentiable Lipschitz function has bounded derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take $x^2$. It is Lipschitz on every <strike>closed</strike> *compact* set but, as you allow the <strike>closed</strike> *compact* sets to get larger and larger, the Lipschitz constant grows to infinity, such that the function is not Lipschitz 'overall'.

Comment: It is Lipschitz on every **compact** set

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the comments. As these two hints are sufficient for the answer, I'll combine them here for you.

**Hint 1 from uniquesolution:** Every continuously differentiable function is locally Lipschitz

**Hint 2 from Sangchul Lee:** Every continuously-differentiable and Lipschitz function on an interval has bounded derivative.

Now, consider the following function
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\sin{(x^2)}.
\end{equation}
Does this function satisfy the first hint? Can you compute the derivative to see that the second hint 'fails'? If this does not clarify the question, let me know in the comments and I will elaborate more.

Comment: Mr. Rice4000,thanks for the answer. I fully understand right now.

Comment: Great! If your question is answered, please consider accepting this answer or Tony S.F. answer. This wat the question will no longer be consider unanswered.